# Error en evento al subir una imágen en Angular

Tags: angular, archivo, imagen, eventos, fileupload

Estoy haciendo una app con el stack MEAN donde en un formulario se pueden subir imágenes, en mi `.ts` tengo esto:

```
interface HtmlInputEvent extends Event {
  target: HTMLInputElement & EventTarget;
}
export class ModalCategoryComponent implements OnInit {

  photoSelected: string | ArrayBuffer;
  file: File;

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onPhotoSelected(event:HtmlInputEvent): void{
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.file = <File>event.target.files[0]
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = e => this.photoSelected = reader.result;
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }
  }

  uploadPhoto(title: HTMLInputElement, description: HTMLTextAreaElement) {
    this.photoService
      .createPhoto(title.value, description.value, this.file)
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log(res);
          this.router.navigate(['/photos'])
        },
        err => console.log(err)
      );
    return false;
  }
}
```

Y en el `.html` tengo lo siguiente para poser subir la imágen:

```
<input type="file" class="d-none" (change)="onPhotoSelected($event)" #photoInput>
<img [src]="photoSelected ||'../../../assets/img/angular.png'" class="img-fluid" (click)="photoInput.click()">
```

El problema que tengo es que en el input en el `(change)="onPhotoSelected($event)"` me da el siguiente error en el `$event`

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'Event' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HtmlInputEvent'.
  Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
    Type 'EventTarget' is not assignable to type 'HTMLInputElement & EventTarget'.
      Type 'EventTarget' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLInputElement': accept, align, alt, autocomplete, and 328 more.

31                                         <input type="file" class="d-none" (change)="onPhotoSelected($event)" #photoInput>
```

Cómo puedo solucionar este error? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Esto es debido a que estas queriendo manejar el parametro del metodo (change)="onPhotoSelected($event) como un HtmlInputElement cuando este no lo es, podrías cambiar el tipo de objeto que esperas y que deserealices el contenido por capas algo así:

```
onPhotoSelect(event:Event):void{
    let input = event.target as HtmlInputElement
    let files = input.files
}
```

donde files ya sería el arreglo donde estan guardados los archivos que seleccionaste en el input.